# Why is Ubuntu One sluggish?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

I have been using Ubuntu One for awhile and I noticed that it is a bit sluggish when it comes to updating the documents in the Ubuntu One folder. I have linked both, my laptop and desktop with Ubuntu One. Why does this situation occur?

I also have a DropBox account and it updates very fast; almost instantaneous. I love my Ubuntu One. Can somebody explain this situation to me?

My Laptop: Acer Aspire 4710 (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) Duo Core, 2GB RAM.

My Desktop: Dell Optiplex 700 (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) Core Duo, 2GB RAM.

Comment: Do you by chance happen to transfer lots of small files?

Comment: Have you tried to upload documents directly on the Ubuntu One website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Stefano's comment might be the root cause of the file sync slowness. This situation is covered in the Ubuntu One FAQ.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsItTakingSoLongForMyFilesToSync

Most users notice this issue when they add a new computer to sync with their Ubuntu One cloud or enable a new folder for syncing... but it generally happens when there are lots of new files to sync. The Ubuntu One team has made improving this experience a priority for the Natty cycle. Most of the enhancements are to the server side so everyone will benefit as they are deployed.

If you see slow file sync and you know that only a few files have changed, it might be related to a temporary disruption. The Ubuntu One status page is a great place to check for this info. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status